# Filter Spark DataFrame if between any set of points in list

Tags: performance, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe (using the scala interface) that has columns of timestamp, asset (a string), tag (a string) and value (a double). Here is an excerpt of it:

```
+--------------------+-----+--------+-------------------+
|           timestamp|asset|     tag|              value|
+--------------------+-----+--------+-------------------+
|2013-01-03 23:36:...|   G4| BTGJ2_2|      116.985626221|
|2013-01-15 00:36:...|   G4| TTXD1_6|       66.887382507|
|2013-01-05 13:03:...|   G4|TTXD1_22|       40.913497925|
|2013-01-12 04:43:...|   G4|TTXD1_23|       60.834510803|
|2013-01-08 17:54:...|   G4|   LTB1D|      106.534744263|
|2013-01-02 04:15:...|   G4|    WEXH|      255.981292725|
|2013-01-07 10:54:...|   G4| BTTA1_7|      100.743843079|
|2013-01-05 11:29:...|   G4| CDFH_10|      388.560668945|
|2013-01-10 09:10:...|   G4|   LTB1D|      112.226242065|
|2013-01-13 15:09:...|   G4|TTXD1_15|       63.970848083|
|2013-01-15 01:23:...|   G4|    TTIB|       67.993904114|
```

I also have an `Array[List[Timestamp]]`, where each `List` is of size two and holds starting and ending times for intervals of interest. For example:

```
event_times: Array[List[java.sql.Timestamp]] = Array(List(2013-01-02 00:00:00.0, 2013-01-02 12:00:00.0), List(2013-01-10 00:00:00.0, 2013-01-12 06:00:00.0))
```

holds two intervals of interest: one from midnight to 12:00 on 2013-01-02, and another from midnight 2013-01-10 to 6:00 on 2013-01-12

Here's my question: How can I filter the dataframe to return values such that the timestamp is in *any* of the intervals? For any one interval, I can do

```
df.filter(df("timestamp").between(start, end))
```

Since I don't know how many elements are in the `Array` (how many intervals I have), I can't just have a long series of filters.

For the example above, I would want to keep rows 4, 6, and 9.

What I have now is a loop over the `Array`, and am getting the appropriate subset for each one. However, that is probably slower than having it all be in a big filter right?

Comment: sorry I didn't get what you want. Can you give a clear example?

Comment: @ThiagoBaldim I just updated with an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your timestamps list into a DataFrame and join it with your initial DataFrame on corresponding timestamps. I've created a simple example to illustrate this process :

```
//Dummy data
val data = List(
  ("2013-01-02 00:30:00.0", "116.985626221"),
  ("2013-01-03 00:30:00.0", "66.887382507"),
  ("2013-01-11 00:30:00.0", "12.3456")
)

//Convert data to DataFrame
val dfData = sc.parallelize(data).toDF("timestamp", "value")

//Timestamp intervals list
val filterList = Array(
  List("2013-01-02 00:00:00.0", "2013-01-02 12:00:00.0"), 
  List("2013-01-10 00:00:00.0", "2013-01-12 06:00:00.0")
)

//Convert the intervals list to a DataFrame
val dfIntervals = sc.parallelize(
  filterList.map(l => (l(0),l(1)))
).toDF("start_ts","end_ts")

//Join both dataframes (inner join, since you only want matching rows)
val joined = dfData.as("data").join(
  dfIntervals.as("inter"), 
  $"data.timestamp".between($"inter.start_ts", $"inter.end_ts")
)
```